# Content Organizer rule and document can not be searchable

Tags: 2010, enterprise-search, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule

There is SharePoint 2010 farm.
I configured content organizer rule to route the document from drop off library to its destination document library according to content type.

When I do this settings I am not able to search the document with its documentID in the site until I run an incremental crawl and 
when I don't create a content organizer rule to a document library and uploads documents I am able to search the document with its document id without running any crawl.
Here I want to know why this behavior and I don't want to run crawl because of some reasons.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The image you show is not a Search Result. New content will not show up in Search Results without a crawl.

Comment: Documents are searchable without crawl when it uploaded to drop off library but not after it routes to document  library by content organizer rule

Comment: What is showing in the crawl log for the destination library.